# FragmentPagerAdapter can't restore listfragment propery

Tags: android, onresume, android-listfragment, fragmentpageradapter

I am developing an Android app made up by 3 fragments; one of them will be a ListFragment, and its content will depend by what happens on the other Fragments. I use a ViewPager object to make the user swype between fragments; this is its adapter class:

```
private class SwypePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private Fragment[] tabFragments; 

    public SwypePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabFragments=new Fragment[NUMBER_OF_TABS];
        tabFragments[0]= Fragment.instantiate(StatCalculatorActivity.this, InsertFrag.class.getName());
        tabFragments[1]= Fragment.instantiate(StatCalculatorActivity.this, ResultFrag.class.getName());
        tabFragments[2]= Fragment.instantiate(StatCalculatorActivity.this, ValuesFrag.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabFragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUMBER_OF_TABS;
    }

}
```

and it all works perfectly fine, until the Activity is destroyed and then recreated. After this the listFragment looks locked, it won't update its data until I destroy and recreate the activity on this fragment. What's going on? How can I restore it?

**UPDATE:**
I don't think I explain what I really mean. It looks like after I destroy and recreate the Activity the fragments are not what they used to be; it's like the old ones overlap the new ones, and they can no longer communicate between each other...just like I lost the references of them, but they are still there...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the data as it is without destroying, you may comment like this in your PagerAdapter

```
@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }
```

Comment: I want to keep data, but there is no way I can get the ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

The fragments are created and destroyed with the activity unless they are set to retain. To maintain your data I would recommend one of two methods:

- make it serializable
- Store it in a retained cache fragment that you connect to on the activity's onCreate

The second method can be implemented by making a fragment and adding the following in the fragment's onCreate and passing the data in before the activity is destroyed on rotate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```